# sychrounous I/O in blktrace

Tags: linux, io, kernel, block, trace

blktrace differentiates synchronous write and asynchronous writes (outputs W or WS).

I am wondering, how does blktrace tell whether an I/O request is synchronous or not? Does it look at some flags in the bio structure?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right. The blktrace(which in kernel space) will check the bio->bi_rw, the flag BIO_RW_SYNCIO. Details are in ./kernel/trace/blktrace.c